# Update View on Component A as Database Update on Component B

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-forms

Component A is a sidebar which 
display List of Categories and initiate only once so can't use ngOnInit

```
College
Faculty
Workshop
Time
Email
```

Component B is Setting component with a form which on submission updates names of these categories and store changes in DB
At present these category names are hard coded
Want to change the view of component A as soon as I update in Component B.

App Structure is

```
app
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|--Admin
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|--Sidebar
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|--sidebar.component.ts
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|--Setting
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|--setting.component.ts
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|--Layout
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|--layout.component.ts
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|--layout.component.html
```

Both components belong to layout component

**layout.component.html**

```
   <sidebar (mouseenter)="mouseEnter()" (mouseleave) = "mouseLeave()"></sidebar>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**For path "/"  -- router outlet display control-home** 
display name of admin

**For path "/control-home/setting"  -- router outlet display setting page**

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({

    moduleId : module.id,
    selector    : 'sidebar',    
    templateUrl : 'sidebar.component.html',
    directives  : [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class SidebarComponent{
}
```

**sidebar.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink] = "['/control-home/setting']" class="enable-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Settings" ><i class="gi gi-cogwheel"></i></a>
```

Setting Component has a form which updates values and store in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a shared service with an observable to notify globally about certain changes and let every interested component act on the notification itself.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: there is no input property to pass. please could you give me some code

Comment: The link provides plenty of code. What do you mean by "there is no input property to pass". An `Observable` allows you to notify other parts of your application that inject the same service instance.

Comment: So if i make a common service and create a function in which observable will return a object or array with category list and in category component I will call that function

Comment: Parent and children communicate via a service is this the way to do it because my components are not parent and child --please respond

Comment: Communication via a service is mostly when there isn't a parent-child relationship. For parent-child you can just use bindings like `[childProp]="parentProp"` or `(childEvent)="doSomethingOnParent($event)"`

Comment: I would create a service with an observable that emits a new array (or object) if values change that need to be propagated. The service can emit new values when another service that updates the database has its request to so so completed successfully. The details depend on what exactly you want to accomplish.